# What affects the Druid beast form attack bonus?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack, druid

I have a Lv1 Razorclaw Shifter, Predator Druid with +5 WIS mod.

**If I'm in beast form and I attack with Grasping Claws, is it really just +5 vs Reflex?**

I don't have a bonus from any implements and I'm under the impression that you drop your weapons (plus he's not Wolverine, a sword in his paw would be weird). Is there any other attack bonus that I'm missing? Am I proficient with claws?

Comment: If you wanna bump see if your dm will let you take an expertise feat to bump it, as Oblivious Sage points out, +5 vs reflex is almost always possibly better than a + 9 vs AC simply because NADs are almost always lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you just have +5 vs reflex.**

Unless you took an expertise feat (such as Totem Expertise<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3671)</sup>) to gain a feat bonus to attack rolls, then the only bonus you're likely to have at level 1 is your wisdom bonus.

The modifier for those attacks is calculated as follows:

- +wisdom modifier (-1 to +10)
- +half your level, rounded down (+0 to +15)
- +implement enhancement bonus (+0 for a non-magical implement, otherwise +1 to +6)
- +feat bonus (+0 if you don't have a feat for it, otherwise +1 to +3)
- +superior implement bonus (+1 if you have an appropriate superior implement and the feat for it)
- +/- any situational modifiers

Note that all druid beast form powers have the implement keyword, and that (as Joshua Aslan Smith pointed out in his answer) you retain the use of implements you were wielding when you entered beast form. This means you gain your implement's enhancement bonus to attack rolls. Also, implement attacks never get a proficiency bonus, so proficiency with claws is a non-issue.

At first level +5 is a perfectly good attack bonus; most enemies are going to have a reflex of 12 or less, so you'll be hitting on a roll of 7+ on a d20.

Comment: +1, Perfect answer, thanks! I'd vote it up for real but I don't have enough rep. :P

Comment: What about expertise feats (staff, totem, and versatile)? Also, accurate implements? or are you including that in feat bonus?

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith: Expertise feats give a feat bonus; good point about the accurate implements, though.

Answer (score 4):

**You still retain the benefits of all worn item and implements**,

> Your equipment becomes part of your beast form, but you drop anything you are holding, except implements you can use. You continue to gain the benefits of the equipment you wear, except a shield.
>       You can use the properties and the powers of implements as well as magic items that you wear, but not the properties or the powers of weapons or the powers of wondrous items. While equipment is part of your beast form, it cannot be removed, and anything in a container that is part of your beast form is inaccessible. - **Player's Handbook 2 p. 82** Retrieved via online Compendium.

So whatever magic enhancement bonus and any feat bonuses to implement attacks (staff/totem expertise, accurate staff/totem implement, etc.) would apply to the to hit roll of attacks while in beast form.

Comment: Also note that Grasping Claws has the implment keyword in the power card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, +5 is your bonus to hit (assuming you have no non-weapon magic items or feats that provide a bonus).

Your bonus to hit = 1/2 level (0) + Ability mod (5) + proficiency bonus (0) + enhancement bonus (0) + feat bonuses (0) +/- situational modifiers (combat advantage, difficult terrain, ect..)

Comment: Forgot to mention that, editing the question right now.